is my cart safe to smoke?
i got a vape device for christmas and noticed it contains HHCO but then upon researching it,came across this https://www.pdx.edu/news/psu-study-shows-vaping-cannabinoid-acetate-leads-formation-deadly-gas
and here is the lab results of the vape cart
https://cdn.prod.website-files.com/62829462cb406845143ba31e/66d75acfe08c8bd4de281f9c_Haze-Pens---Midnight.pdf
is this cart safe to smoke at all?

Vaping in general is not a healthy practice
